# Finding top 10 trending tweets in Hive

Tags: sql, twitter, hive, hiveql, mysql-logic

I am finding top 10 trending tweets in hive on basis of retweet_count
ie The tweet which has highest retweet_count will be 1st and so-on....

Here is election Table details

```
id                      bigint                  from deserializer   
created_at              string                  from deserializer   
source                  string                  from deserializer   
favorited               boolean                 from deserializer   
retweeted_status        struct<text:string,user:struct<screen_name:string,name:string>,retweet_count:int>   from deserializer   
entities                struct<urls:array<struct<expanded_url:string>>,user_mentions:array<struct<screen_name:string,name:string>>,hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>> from deserializer   
text                    string                  from deserializer   
user                    struct<screen_name:string,name:string,friends_count:int,followers_count:int,statuses_count:int,verified:boolean,utc_offset:int,time_zone:string,location:string>    from deserializer   
in_reply_to_screen_name string                  from deserializer
```

my query

```
select text 
from election 
where retweeted_status.retweet_count IN  
     (select  retweeted_status.retweet_count as zz 
      from election  
      order by zz desc  
      limit 10);
```

It is returning me the same tweet 10 times.
(TWEET-ABC,
TWEET-ABC,
TWEET-ABC,
.
.
.
TWEET-ABC)

So what I did is break the nested query , when I run inner query

```
select  retweeted_status.retweet_count as zz 
from election  
order by zz desc  
limit 10
```

It return 10 different values (1210,1209,1208,1207,1206,....1201)

Afterwards when I run my outer query

```
select text 
from election  
where retweeted_status.retweet_count 
      IN  (1210,1209,1208,1207,1206,....1201 );
```

The results are same 10 tweets 
(TWEET-ABC,
TWEET-ABC,
TWEET-ABC,
.
.
.
TWEET-ABC)

Whats wrong in my query logic ?

Comment: Im not familiar with tweets and re-tweets... but maybe you have most retweet `{tweet-abc, retweet 1209}`, then you retweet again you have `{tweet-abc, retweet 1210}` so you most retweet is the same... just is \growing

Comment: did you read my comment? any toughts? show us sample data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using count you should use id. that is because if you have 100 tweet with same count not matter the LIMIT 10 you will get 100 records.

```
select text 
from election 
where id  IN  
     (select  id as zz 
      from election  
      order by retweeted_status.retweet_count desc  
      limit 10);
```

but still not sure why are you getting the wrong result.

**EDIT** (after my comment):

if my comment is correct then you will have the same id ten times. In that case change to

```
     (select distinct id as zz 
      from election  
      order by retweeted_status.retweet_count desc  
      limit 10);
```

Comment: select  id   from election  order by retweeted_status.retweet_count desc limit 10;   It is giving me an error  "SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:38 Invalid table alias or column reference 'retweeted_status': (possible column names are: id)"

Comment: select * from election     order by retweeted_status.retweet_count desc limit 10; is working but  select id from election     order by retweeted_status.retweet_count desc limit 10; is not working error is "Invalid table alias or column reference 'retweeted_status': (possible column names are: id)"

Comment: The logic is there. I dont know how hive handle complex object or your model. Please check your query.

Comment: select * from election order by retweeted_status.retweet_count ; works wel .select id from election order by retweeted_status.retweet_count: gives error ""Invalid table alias or column reference 'retweeted_status': (possible column names are: id)""

Comment: again you know your schema, you say there is one `id` column there. and you understand my comment about why is the same tweet as the most retweeted?

Comment: select text from election where id IN ( select distinct  a.id from  (select id,retweeted_status.retweet_count  from election  order by retweet_count desc limit 10) as a )  ;  This query also returns me all same result